# Replacing commas in a csv file with sed for mongoimport

Tags: bash, csv, sed, mongoimport

I have a `csv` file and I need to replace all the commas with dots. In other words, I need only the semicolon as a separator, and the commas need to be replaced with dots.
I need this in order to import the data with `mongoimport`.
I used the sed command, but it does not replace every occurrency of comma. For example:

```
Zolmitriptan;6 UNITA' 2,5 MG - USO ORALE;N02CC03;33345149;ZOMIG RAPIMELT;"""2,5 MG COMPRESSE ORODISPERSIBILI"" 6 COMPRESSE IN BLISTER";ASTRAZENECA S.P.A.;17,84;20,84;;3,00;FUB
```

becomes this , with `sed 's/\,/\./' <filename>`:

```
Zolmitriptan;6 UNITA' 2.5 MG - USO ORALE;N02CC03;33345149;ZOMIG RAPIMELT;"""2,5 MG COMPRESSE ORODISPERSIBILI"" 6 COMPRESSE IN BLISTER";ASTRAZENECA S.P.A.;17,84;20,84;;3,00;FUB
```

Notice that only the first comma was replaced. What am I doing wrong?

PS. Is there a way to make mongoimport ignore the commas? (in this case I would not need the replacement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not using the global option, so

```
sed 's/\,/\./g'
```

is now working.
The question remains open for the mongoimport alternative, though!

Comment: no need to escape either character. `,` is not a metacharacter at any time and `.` is not one in the replacement string context.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a "sed" command line that works.
It takes a file as input and replace any , following a digit (0-9) with a dot .

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\),/\1./g' your_file.csv
```

## Comments:

- -i  stands for "inplace" : The file is treated itself. Be careful, there is no backup !
- sed -i 's/blabla/foofoo/g' would replace any occurrence of blabla with foofoo. The last g option means replace more than one time in each line if blabla is found several times.
- [0-9] means any digit from 0 to 9.
- ([0-9]) Parentheses are used to store the digit before the comma. Parentheses must be escaped.
- \1 is used to call what was stored and get it back in result just before the dot. It must be escaped too.

## Example:

*your_file.csv before*

```
stuff 12,004 hello -78,1
anything456,78 what else 98765
```

**Run following line**

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\),/\1./g' your_file.csv
```

*your_file.csv after*

```
stuff 12.004 hello -78.1
anything456.78 what else 98765
```

Comment: I solved the problem a very long time ago but I appreciate your complete answer. Didn't know about the -i option! Here's an upvote!

Comment: Nice. Smart move